# How to add, additional prismatic joint to the end of Universal robot last joint inside URDF file?

Tags: ros, industrial-robot

Could you please tell me how can I add, additional prismatic joint to the end 6th joint in URDF file of an Universal robot as in the link below:

https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/kinetic-devel/ur_description/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "***end** of an URDF file*"?

The last two links (`wrist_3_link` and `ee_link`) are connected by a `fixed` joint. Change the joint [type](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#Attributes) to `prismatic` and then update the joint properties (joint axis and joint limits).

Or do you want to add an additional link to the manipulator i.e. add a new link after `ee_link`? In that case, define a new [link](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link) with a unique name, for eg. `new_link`. Then, define a prismatic joint with *parent* as `ee_link` and *child* as `new_link`.

Comment: Yes I would like to add an additional prismatic joint to the 6th joint. What about other parameters? As far as I see it is not that straight forward.

Comment: @MericOzcan It is pretty straightforward once you know what the various "elements" of a joint and link mean, check  http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint#Elements and http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link#Elements

Comment: Did you ever try something like that? if you didn't, probably you dont know how complex it might go.